# Missing Magento Pagination on my Brands page

Tags: php, html, magento

I was hoping somebody could point me in the right direction with a Magento issue I'm having. On my 'Brands' page I'm missing the pagination on the bottom. My page is calling the correct toolbar with the pager included. Its displaying how many products there are, and how many products i can view on each page, but its not rendering the Pagination. All my other pages work great, just have been super stuck when it comes to the brands page. Here is the example:

http://www.strivved.com/brand/Champion.html

When you scroll to the bottom you can see the pagination is missing. I've tried updating the toolbar.phtml and even pager.phtml. They all work and render fine on all my other pages, just not on any of the pages rendered from brands/BRANDNAME.html. Anyone have any suggestions. I appreciate the input. Thanks!

Comment: Seems you solved the problem yourself?

Comment: Yes I did! With a help from a colleague.  Is there a way i should close out the question?

Comment: You can self answer your question and accept that answer http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer